# How do I sort a collection of eloquent objects in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent

Given a successful fetch from the DB via Laravel Eloquent and deeper related objects as attributes - how do I sort deep by sub object attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sortBy` method with an accessor attribute:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
    }
}

$users = MyModel::all()->sortBy('name');
```

Comment: hi Joseph, thanks for your input.  I'm trying to make a post for everyone to help with more deep/powerful sorting, rather than the simple bits.  Can you help by editing my question toward that effort?

Answer (score 1):

```
$stuff = MyModel::all();
$sortedStuff = $stuff->sort(function($a, $b)
{
    $a = $a->getMyCalculatedAttribute();
    $b = $b->getMyCalculatedAttribute();
    //here you can do more complex comparisons
    //when dealing with sub-objects and child models
    if ($a->property === $b->property) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->property > $b->property) ? 1 : -1;
});
```